# What coordinate system and bounds should I use when integrating this function in three dimensions?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $R_1$ be the region bounded above by $z=2$ and below by the cone $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$ for $z \geq 0$.

Can you please specify the boundaries of the integral and whether I should use cylindrical, spherical, or rectangular coordinates.

Comment: That cone is, in fact, a double one, and it is unbounded from below. Perhaps you meant for $\;z\ge 0\;$ ?

Comment: yes z is greater than 0

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: In cylindrical coords volume enclosed between surface of revolution $ z=1/r ,$ plane $ z=2 $ and cone $z=r$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without even looking at the function to be integrated, the boundaries scream cylindrical coordinates to me. Specifically, note the following:
$$x^2+y^2-z^2=0$$
$$r^2-z^2=0$$
$$r=z.$$
Since the top of the region to be integrated over is bounded by $z=2$, this gives us our $z$ bounds: $[r,2]$.

Can you complete the problem from here?

Comment: I think , are the bounds of r [0,2] and those of theta [0,2pi]?

Comment: @NourShami precisely. If you wouldn't mind upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you, that would be much appreciated